# Can apache basic authentication work well on a custom SSL port

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

This is for a legacy system running Apache 2.2, and for various reasons, the secure webserver can't run on port 443 (that port is used by something else). So it's configured to run on port 8443, and I have this line in the non-SSL configuration which redirects all requests to the 'admin' pages to the secure connection:

```
RewriteRule ^/admin(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8443/admin [R=302,L]
```

That works fine - if you attempt to browse to:

```
http://server.com/admin
```

you are redirected correctly to:

```
https://server.com:8443/admin
```

At that point, an authentication form appears to log in, with `AuthType` set to `Digest`. That seems to work fine, but on entering a valid username and password, the browser is redirected to:

```
https://server.com/admin
^^^^^             ^
```

Note the missing port number. Now, if you start off by typing the full correct address into the browser:

```
https://server.com:8443/admin
```

then the same apache authentication form appears, but this time after logging in, the port number is retained, and the admin page is displayed.

So, my question is, without changing the port numbers, can I make the non-SSL page redirect to the SSL page in a way that preserves the port number *after* authentication? I couldn't find anything in the Auth Digest documentation about port numbers, but I'm presuming it's something to do with the original URI being either from the browser request, or the rewrite rule.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the relevant parts of the configuration.

Comment: This maybe a problem of how Apache creates self referential URLs (though I don't see how, I tested your config and I do not see what you are seeing). Add the output of `apachectl -S` to your post, and if possible the contents of the port 8443 vhost.

Comment: OK - first of all, apologies for not posting the full config. Long, complex file, and not sure what I could cut without changing the problem. So, I created a minimal test config now posted as an answer below. Let me know if this shouldn't really be the answer but a different question...

Answer (score 1):

Basic authentication can be done on any port. Basic authentication also does authentication for a specific resource and does not involve any redirects at all: instead it just requests the same URL again after the password dialog but this time with credentials inside the HTTP request. Since no redirect is involved with basic authentication this means that the redirect you see is not caused by the authentication but is explicitly configured somewhere in your config.

Answer (score 0):

I created a minimal test case, which what I *think* is the answer. Please comment if this isn't the case, or if it's just a horrible hack workaround something else.

Non-SSL conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.com
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/secret(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8443/secret [R=302,L]
    RewriteRule ^/public(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8443/public [R=302,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

SSL conf:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
NameVirtualHost *:8443
Listen *:8443

<VirtualHost *:8443>
    ServerName server.com:8443
    UseCanonicalName On
    SSLEngine on

    # SSL cert/key
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/cert.chain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/cert.key

    DocumentRoot    "/var/www"

    <Directory "/var/www/public">
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
      Options -Indexes FollowSymlinks
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/secret">
      DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
      AuthName "Secret Pages"
      AuthType Digest
      AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/test-digests
      Require valid-user
      Options -Indexes FollowSymlinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from localhost.localdomain
      Satisfy any
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Note the `ServerName` line in the SSL configuration. If I *don't* put the non-standard port there, then the Digest redirect appears to use the standard https port 443 once the username / password has been entered, which results in the behaviour I outlined in the original question. Once the port is there, the behaviour is as required.

So it appears, at least from this, that if SSL is running on a non-standard port, and using Digest (or I guess Basic) apache authentication, it's necessary to specify the port in the ServerName configuration. This is something I hadn't seen from the documentation.

Comment: Like I theorised in my original comment, it seems to be something to do with the way Apache creates self referential URLs, but I've been unable to replicate it myself.

Comment: Yes, and this is not the whole story either, because with anything other than a trivial `index.html` file in the protected area, I'm getting an infinite loop in the rewrite log coming from the *:80 section. Without that rewrite rule, I see a series of requests for the assets etc. But when that rule is there, I see an initial request from my IP for /secret, followed by an endless series of requests for /secret coming from 127.0.0.1. I will keep poking at it.

Comment: If you could show us the `rewritelog` it *might* help ...

Comment: Yeah, sorry. There's a lot of stuff in there that I can't share without loads of editing, but I eventually managed to create a minimal test case (in terms of config) with the real application. It turns out there were loads of things in the app PHP like `file_get_contents('http://server.com/admin/some-resource.php')` which was being rewritten to the secure URL. So I added in a condition to exclude `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` == 127.0.0.1 and the rewrite loop went away. But I still have to put :8443 on the ServerName line. Otherwise the initial authentication redirects to the wrong place.